# what are the restrictions for java Applet?

Tags: java, awt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Restrictions on what an unsigned Java applet can do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1483595/restrictions-on-what-an-unsigned-java-applet-can-do)

I would like to know about what are the restrictions for using java Applet.I mean, What are applets prevented from doing?

Comment: The duplicate question contains a great list!  Together with Tom Hawtin's clarification/updates, it represents a better list than is linked in the accepted answer of either this or that question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look this article, [what applet can do and cannot do.](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/security.html) Also search on [google](http://www.google.co.in/#sclient=psy&hl=en&biw=1280&bih=658&source=hp&q=restriction%20of%20applets&pbx=1&oq=restriction%20of%20app&aq=1j&aqi=g-j4g-m1&aql=&gs_sm=sc&gs_upl=972l9038l0l11254l21l21l0l1l1l2l785l4735l2.7.8.0.1.1.1l20l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=a0cad3eeb24ccfaf&pf=p&pdl=300) and find many answers.

Answer (score 1):

It depends whether you sign them or not. Following link contains detailed information regarding this topic:
http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/security.html

Answer (score 1):

Applets are basically used for small programs that can be downloaded on to a clients system to perform small task,Eg a calculator ,they are limited in many ways

1.they need to be small,as the main purpose of an applet is to delegate the work of a server and more over you wanna reduce your download done by your clients

2.they have limited functionality as they cannot access any information on your system for any kinda of processing,which also makes them safe and secure

3.they are strictly limited to the web browser

and finally,they are generally used for user inputs and small stuff and also limited by the API s using awt which are mostly GUI related

sorry if i didn't answer your question exactly,but that's pretty much what i know on java applets :P