# Java Read File Permissions

Tags: java, security, exception, permissions, policy

I was wondering if anybody can show me way to be able to create read file permissions for my java applet.

The exact exception I receive is

```
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied(java.io.FilePermission filename.pdf write)
```

I've put `f.setReadable` and `f.setWriteable` where `f` is the file and nothing. A little help please.

Comment: Whoops, I meant to say write permissions, though I'm not sure why I need write when all I'm doing is reading PDF and printing it.

Comment: have you tried f.setReadable(true) and f.setWriteable(true)?

Comment: yes, sorry i meant true for both of those methods. Wouldn't work. I figure its easiest way to set permissions this way

Comment: Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command); where your command could be something like chmod 777 + path + f

Comment: @user1022570 Assuming you want to access a file on the computer running the applet in a browser, have you [signed your applet](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/JDCBook/signed.html)? Only signed applets can access (read/write) the local file system of the computer running an applet, i.e. leave the "sandbox".

Answer (score 2):

There's security limits on what an unsigned applet can do, and one of the things it can't do is access the local filesystem (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1483595/restrictions-on-what-an-unsigned-java-applet-can-do) for a full list).  You have several options:

1. [Sign your applet](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~lsiden/tutorials/signed-applet/signed-applet.html).  If a user then runs your applet it won't run with any security restrictions.  However, signing your applet with a trusted certificate costs at least $100 a year, and if you self-sign then nobody is going to trust your applet.  And even if you do sign with a trusted certificate the user might decide not to run it.
2. Set up your applet with [a JNLP file](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/jws/developersguide/syntax.html).  This will let your applet use the [javax.jnlp](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/jre/api/javaws/jnlp/) package.  You can then use the `FileOpenService` and `FileSaveService` to ask the user to let you read/write one particular file.  Alternatively, you can use the `PersistenceService` to store a small amount of data persistently within the browser.

Comment: +1 for JNLP, it's both easier to do local file access with the mentioned services but also the whole deployment is easier (libraries, JVM versions, HTML code).